# What can I do when a thread from an external library crashes my application unpredictably?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, crash

My application uses a camera library which shall send images to my application continuously. Unfortunately this library starts a thread which throws an exception (or causes an exception to be thrown) and doesn't handle it. As a result the entire application crashes. Is there a way to prevent the application from crashing? Can I install an exception handler on a thread externally?

Some details about my specific situation: There's no function in the call stack of the crashing thread, that I have control over. I don't even know what exactly the thread is there for. But I stop the program with the debugger, I can tell which thread it is, that is going to crash. Unfortunately, the thread crashes very randomly, sometimes it takes more than an hour until something happens. I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010, the debugger tells me, it's a std::bad_alloc.

Comment: if you very hard working then I will suggest `code injection`. :)

Comment: sacrifice a chicken and two cows.

Comment: You are hilarious! :D But seriously, the deadline for this project is next week and the application must work by then.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24417/Portable-Executable-P-E-Code-Injection-Injecting-a

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the library ? When the crash occurs what's the memory usage of your application ? std::bad_alloc means unable to allocate memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trap the exception by installing a callback with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter.  And kill the thread when it fires.

Nevertheless, the exception is a nasty one.  The common cause for std::bad_alloc is not just running out of memory, it can also be triggered by a corrupted heap.  Both are unrecoverable conditions, killing the thread doesn't restore leaked memory and doesn't un-corrupt the heap.  Furthermore, you've leaked the thread's stack by killing the thread.  And the odds that you'll get the camera going are very slight in general, it will very likely just bomb again quickly.  Only consider trying this iff your program can continue to be useful without the camera.

Running it out of process so you can afford to lose the state entirely is an option, but the process interop you'll need it painful and relatively expensive.

If you can't get support from the vendor then you need to go shopping again.

Comment: Do you know by chance how long it takes to copy 1 MB to shared memory and copy it out from there by another process? A rough statement would suffice.

Comment: About one microsecond setup plus 5 GB/sec copy plus thread context switch overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I have not dealt with Windows so I cannot provide you a specific way of doing this but here are two ideas that I think are applicable to any modern OS.

#### Move that library out of your process

You can create a "helper" application that acts like a bridge between your "master" application and a library. This way, when "helper" application crashes or starts malfunctioning (i.e. uses way too much memory etc), you can safely bounce it without affecting  the main application. Any IPC means can be used to establish communication between that "helper" and your master application.

#### Intercept and control threads of the "bad" library

You can hook/intercept/overload system calls for a process (in POSIX-like OS there are few ways of doing that, but the easiest is to use `LD_PRELOAD` variable and pre-load shared object with the code. Windows does provide similar functionality, I don't reckon what it is called though).

Then, you can inject your own code that could wrap third-party library's thread routine in a try-catch block by intercepting a thread creation routine/system call (`CreateThread`?).

This will work technically, but what I am afraid of is that you cannot really tell that library will continue functioning properly after you catch and suppress that exception. So the first approach is more likely to work well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought about launching a new process and doing interprocess communication. My concern is that the lag of the camera acquisition to screen display will be even larger than now. The frame rate can probably be kept. Possibly this will be the only alternative though, since after the exception the library (if not my whole application) might stop to work.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: if I were you I'd consider giving that library's authors some hard time and get them fixing the problem, or ask them to disclose the protocol, or even reverse-engineering the protocol and writing my own library to capture images from the cam. If they use some standard protocol, for example, it could be a matter of hooking up some of the open source libraries for example.